# publishing XML messages from Zerocode to Kafka topic

Tags: xml, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, avro

I am trying integration testing for streaming platform ( Kafka / spark ) using [zerocode](https://authorjapps.github.io/zerocode/)

zero code (publish XML Message )-->  serialize with Apache AVRO --> Kafka topic --> spark job (processing) --> Kafka topic --> deserialize with AVRO -->zero code consumer Test ( assert for message content )

when i am trying to put message on Kafka topic with zero code , zero code test case introduce special char at start of XML message , which cause error while parsing XML message in spark .

when I work with string serializer and "hello world" it work .

I need to make it work with Apache Avro and XML message  .

```
{
  "scenario Name": "Produce a message to Kafka topic - vanilla",
  "steps": [
    {
      "name": "produce_step",
      "URL": "Kafka-topic: my-topic ",
      "operation": "produce",
      "request": {
        "record Type" : "J SON",
        "records": [
          {
            "key":"123456789",
            "value": "Schema Test"
          }
        ]
      },
      "assertions": {
        "record Metadata" : "$NOT.NULL",
        "status" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

when zero code test case put message on Kafka topic , it should not introduce any special char at start of message .

Comment: key.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

Comment: Error :Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)

Comment: scenarioName": "Produce a message to kafka topic - ",
  "steps": [
    {
      "name": "produce_step",
      "url": "kafka-topic:mytopic",
          "operation": "produce",
      "request": {
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "xml; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        "recordType" : "RAW",
        "records": [
                    {
            "key": "1",
            "value": "<? xml version=\"1.0\" 
          }
                  ]
      },
      "assertions": {
        "status" : "Ok",
        "recordMetadata" : "$NOT.NULL"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these details and format your JSON config

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. XML cannot just instantly become Avro. Is zerocode supposed to be parsing XML? If so, 1) your XML is not complete `"<? xml version=\"1.0\"` 2) the documentation on the raw type seems to say it's just produced as a string, which would just be an Avro string,, so why use Avro at all if you're not saving yourself any costs of storing UTF8 data?

Comment: I have not posted full XML .

Comment: Okay. Anyway, where are you seeing this "special char" exactly? Can you show the character n the question and your integration test cases?

Comment: The example tests show how to consume and produce Avro, by the way but it requires going through the REST Proxy... https://github.com/authorjapps/hello-kafka-stream-testing/tree/master/src/test/resources/kafka/consume

Comment: https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/blob/da2a4af91a06905a0fe31c24b313fd6633cb91ed/kafka-testing/src/test/resources/kafka_servers/kafka_consumer_avro.properties
https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/blob/da2a4af91a06905a0fe31c24b313fd6633cb91ed/kafka-testing/src/test/resources/kafka/consume/test_kafka_consume_avro_msg_raw_int.json

Comment: special char is at start of xml .

Comment: Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)

Comment: Well, you can't use KafkaAvroDeserializer with XML data. It's just a String, and that deserializer knows nothing about parsing XML content. Just use Kafka regular StringSerializer and you shouldn't get special characters... If you really need Avro, you must code the XML translation and parsing on your own (and unit test it outside of zerocode)

Comment: And please add the full stacktrace for that error to the question

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the "record Type" to `RAW` instead of `JSON`. It should work as expected.

> `"record Type" : "RAW"`

e.g.

You want to produce the below XML message to a Kafka topic, then consume the XML from the Kafka topic and verify the XML was the same.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConversionRate xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>
      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>
    </ConversionRate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Full test case is below for your reference. It has both "produce" and "consume" steps.

```
{
    "scenarioName": "Produce and Consume XML as RAW message",
    "steps": [
        {
            "name": "load_kafka",
            "url": "kafka-topic:demo-raw1",
            "operation": "load",
            "request": {
                "record Type" : "RAW",
                "records": [
                    {
                        "key": "${RANDOM.NUMBER}",
                        "value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Body>\n    <ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">\n      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>\n      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>\n    </ConversionRate>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "assertions": {
                "status": "Ok"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "onload_kafka",
            "url": "kafka-topic:demo-raw1",
            "operation": "unload",
            "request": {
                "consumerLocalConfigs": {
                    "recordType": "RAW",
                    "commitSync": true,
                    "showRecordsConsumed": true,
                    "maxNoOfRetryPollsOrTimeouts": 3
                }
            },
            "assertions": {
                "size": 1,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "key" : "$NOT.NULL",
                        "value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Body>\n    <ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">\n      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>\n      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>\n    </ConversionRate>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Zerocode test-run console log below after consuming the record, i.e. the consumed XML is exactly identical to the XML as produced.

```
org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.receive.KafkaReceiver - Consumer chosen recordType: RAW
2020-05-19 12:32:28,986 [main] INFO  
org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.helper.KafkaConsumerHelper - 
Record Key - 6784799632078391362 , 
Record value - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConversionRate xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>
      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>
    </ConversionRate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>, 

Record partition - 0, Record offset - 1
```

You can see the full log below:

```
2020-05-19 12:32:25,358 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl - 
-------------------------- BDD: Scenario:consume as RAW message -------------------------

2020-05-19 12:32:25,461 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.helper.KafkaConsumerHelper - 
---------------------------------------------------------
kafka.bootstrap.servers - localhost:9092
---------------------------------------------------------
returned default type 'RAW'.
2020-05-19 12:32:25,677 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.send.KafkaSender - Sending record number: 0

2020-05-19 12:32:25,678 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.send.KafkaSender - Synchronous Producer sending record - ProducerRecord(topic=demo-raw1, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=6784799632078391362, value=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConversionRate xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>
      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>
    </ConversionRate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>, timestamp=null)


2020-05-19 12:32:25,873 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.engine.validators.ZeroCodeValidatorImpl - Comparing results via LENIENT matchers
2020-05-19 12:32:25,878 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.StepNotificationHandler - 
***Step PASSED - Scenario:consume as RAW message -> load_kafka
2020-05-19 12:32:25,882 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl - 
--------- TEST-STEP-CORRELATION-ID: a8ebe4c6-c1fb-434c-9c00-b2cbdf2f7fe6 ---------
*requestTimeStamp:2020-05-19T12:32:25.455
step:load_kafka
url:kafka-topic:demo-raw1
method:load
request:
{
  "record Type" : "RAW",
  "records" : [ {
    "key" : "6784799632078391362",
    "value" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Body>\n    <ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">\n      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>\n      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>\n    </ConversionRate>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
  } ]
} 
--------- TEST-STEP-CORRELATION-ID: a8ebe4c6-c1fb-434c-9c00-b2cbdf2f7fe6 ---------
Response:
{
  "status" : "Ok",
  "recordMetadata" : {
    "offset" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1589887945831,
    "serializedKeySize" : 19,
    "serializedValueSize" : 407,
    "topicPartition" : {
      "hash" : 749906548,
      "partition" : 0,
      "topic" : "demo-raw1"
    }
  }
}
*responseTimeStamp:2020-05-19T12:32:25.872 
*Response delay:417.0 milli-secs 
---------> Expected Response: <----------
{
  "status" : "Ok"
} 

-done-

2020-05-19 12:32:25,884 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.helper.KafkaConsumerHelper - 
---------------------------------------------------------
kafka.bootstrap.servers - localhost:9092
---------------------------------------------------------

***Step PASSED - Scenario:consume as RAW message -> onload_kafka
2020-05-19 12:32:33,025 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl - 
--------- TEST-STEP-CORRELATION-ID: 53092b7e-ae92-4631-ad79-0602280650b9 ---------
*requestTimeStamp:2020-05-19T12:32:25.884
step:onload_kafka
url:kafka-topic:demo-raw1
method:unload
request:
{
  "consumerLocalConfigs" : {
    "recordType" : "RAW",
    "commitSync" : true,
    "showRecordsConsumed" : true,
    "maxNoOfRetryPollsOrTimeouts" : 3
  }
} 
--------- TEST-STEP-CORRELATION-ID: 53092b7e-ae92-4631-ad79-0602280650b9 ---------
Response:
{
  "records" : [ {
    "topic" : "demo-raw1",
    "partition" : 0,
    "offset" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1589887945831,
    "timestampType" : "CREATE_TIME",
    "serializedKeySize" : 19,
    "serializedValueSize" : 407,
    "key" : "6784799632078391362",
    "value" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Body>\n    <ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">\n      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>\n      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>\n    </ConversionRate>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>",
    "leaderEpoch" : {
      "value" : 0
    }
  } ],
  "size" : 1
}
*responseTimeStamp:2020-05-19T12:32:33.020 
*Response delay:7136.0 milli-secs 
---------> Expected Response: <----------
{
  "size" : 1,
  "records" : [ {
    "key" : "$NOT.NULL",
    "value" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Body>\n    <ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">\n      <FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>\n      <ToCurrency>GBP</ToCurrency>\n    </ConversionRate>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
  } ]
} 

-done-


2020-05-19 12:32:33,233 [main] INFO  org.jsmart.zerocode.core.domain.builders.ExtentReportsFactory - Where were the tests fired? Ans: OS:Mac OS X, Architecture:x86_64, Java:1.8.0_91, Vendor:Oracle Corporation

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the Wiki and help docs for [Kafka Produce Consume XML messages](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki/Producing-and-consuming-XML-message-to-and-from-a-Kafka-topic)

Answer (score 0):

> special char is at start of xml

If I understand correctly, you're trying to make XML into Avro...

Based on what I've read about zerocode, that isn't possible, and the least it would do would be to convert a UTF-8 string into an Avro UTF-8 String, which you could simulate the same thing completely outside of zerocode.

1. Start Schema Registry and Kafka
2. Create a topic

   ```
   kafka-topics --create --topic sample --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions=1 --replication-factor=1
   ```
3. Produce "XML" string to a topic using `kafka-avro-console-producer`

   ```
   kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:29092 --topic sample --property value.schema='{"type":"string"}'
   "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
   ```
4. (Optional) Look at the schema registry to verify schema is there

   ```
   curl -s localhost:8081/subjects/sample-value/versions/latest | jq
   {
     "subject": "sample-value",
     "version": 1,
     "id": 29,
     "schema": "\"string\""
   }
   ```
5. Use `kafka-console-consumer` (which uses StringDeserializer) to inspect the message. **We notice it has a "special character"**

   ```
   kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sample --from-beginning
   *<?xml version="1.0"?>
   ```
6. Use `kafka-avro-console-consumer` (which uses KafkaAvroDeserializer), and we see the value is surrounded by quotes (because the representation is a JSON string), but the "special character" **is gone**.

   ```
   kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sample --from-beginning
   "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
   ```

So, I don't have your Spark code to know where your error is happening, but [`spark-xml` package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) doesn't know anything about Avro data (i.e. it cannot parse that "special character", which is actually an Avro ID in the registry) and [`spark-avro`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) doesn't know anything about how a Schema Registry is used, so my suggestion would be to *forget about Avro* since you are really only dealing with Strings anyway.